# Activity crash when using sqllite in my custom class - android

Tags: java, android

So i created this class :

```
public class Database extends Activity {
    public SQLiteDatabase db ;

    public void openDb(){
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("myDB",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.close();
    }   
}
```

And in my main activity i wrote that :

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Database ODB= new Database ();
        ODB.openDb();

    }
}
```

When I launch that I get force closing windows and when I put that in try-catch I get `NullPointerException` .

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: go through the tutorial on android hive for simple example of sqlite in android. Its always advisable to use a separate DataBaseHandler( extends SQLiteHelper) class in apps having databases.Then you can go on, Create your database, add tables, insert values by executing simple queries. And from your activity class you can call methods defined in the Handler class for doing the database operations.

Comment: can u show us the logcat output?

Answer (score 0):

Since database is static why are you trying open db in other class.

Try this

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("myDB",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

    }}
```

Comment: i am trying to create a custom class that i could mannage my tables .

Comment: i am new in java and android , i'm coming from php background .in my php project i did abstract class database that know how to save update delete and so on and for example if i have a user table so i created user class that extends the database thus know how to communicate with the db . (sorry for my english..) i am implement the same idea in my android project...